# Is TOA reflectance in floating point or DN?

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine

After  converting at radiance to TOA reflectance,is going to be in DN or floating point.

Comment: What sensor are you working with?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, DN is te value assigned to a pixel in a digital image, so you'll always have DN's. However, it is mostly used for the raw image values, coming directly from the sensor (usually after some recalibration to optimize the use of a pixel depth and correct some internal sensor errors).

TOA reflectance is the value of the reflectance on Top of Atmosphere (in other words, the effect of the atmosphere is not corrected). Reflectance is a proportion of the sun light that is reflected by an object. As a proportion, reflectance should be a value between 0 (everything is absorbed and/or transmitted) and 1 (everything is reflected). But sometimes it is stored as an integer value (e.g. multiplied by 100, 255 or 10000) for more efficient storage than a floating point (respectively 8bit, 8bit and Uint16).